# Solar config for small LED project

Tags: led, batteries, solar-cell

I want to work on a project to control LED lights from my Raspberry Pi 3b, I want to have 6 led strips with 300 LED each (https://goo.gl/1bwwe0), connected to the raspberry and control them with my mobile.

That's the first part of my proyect, but what I want is to have it connected with solar power.

What I don't know is what to buy and how to make the configuration of the hardware

Sun -> Solar Panel -> Something -> ... -> Battery -> maybe something? -> Raspberry

Can you help me to choose the best items for my project? (good relation price/quality)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you done the math yet?

Comment: 1) This is too broad for Q & A format; 2) Not much research and effort seems to be done; 3) Shopping questions are off topic.

Comment: Small led project Bwahahahahaha you funny.  That's a few amps your talking about.

Comment: I was amazed at the low price of that LED strip before I realised it was a single-colour one. (I have a similar one, but RGB-addressable and with half the LEDs, that cost around US$80)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- 6x24W =144W implies you need a PV  solar W = 144W* discharge time / charge time * charger efficiency * solar efficiency * battery efficiency
- then a battery with greater Ah rating for one day with discharge time * 6* 2A to cover lack of input during overcast days.

Considering the cost of electricity just for 144W, an old car battery and 6A trickle charger is all you need.  You will want this because at 12 V it will be almost half dim compared to the std rating for stripleds at 14.2V

These are cheap BTW , because few people like cool white (bluish)

Comment: And can you tellme what is the correct order of the items?
Sun -> Solar Panel -> what here? -> Battery -> what here? -> Raspberry

Thanks!